# EditText ,Saving a string as a Double Android Programming?

Tags: android, double

I recently learned to save the user entered information as an integer and wanted to know how i would save it as a double , in case the answer to a basic equation had a decimal.
 Heres the relevant code

```
 String data = feet.getText().toString();
 final int dataint = Integer.parseInt(data);


 displayText.setText((dataint / formula) + " Yards");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final double datadouble = Double.valueOf(data);
```

This is a basic Java question. Please try [Google](http://www.google.com) and/or research before you post a question.

Comment: I know, its hard for me to find someone using it in the same way and im just started so its difficult for me to convert other peoples solutions to my own, but i will delve a little further first next time.

Comment: You can search Google with "casting double to int java" or switch java to Android. Should give you detail results and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It may help you

```
 double dataDouble = Double.valueOf(dataint);
```

It will convert the "dataint" integer value to double type.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt` for int and [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) for double